# How to Detect Question Mark Invalid Character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in a database that accepts imported files. When the client enters a registered trademark, copyright, or another invalid symbol, the database imports the symbol as an invalid character in the form of a question mark, like the following:
[image]

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur � lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
```

When printing this character, it appears as such:
[image]

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ? lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
```

Is there a way to detect that symbol, as using a *like* statement doesn't detect the symbol.

The desired result is to be able to send a warning in a stored procedure that asks the user to check the inserted data to ensure validity.

Note: It is not enough to insert the string into a temp table and then check the temp table for question marks, as a question mark in the string is not uncommon and would create for more false positives than helpful alerts.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "when printing? As in `PRINT`?

Comment: @Larnu yes, when writing

print 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur � lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'

Comment: Are you using a `varchar` or `nvarchar` literal/variable? `�` is can't be represented in a `varchar` value. `PRINT N'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur � lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur';` works fine.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "Unicode replacement character". Though SQL can handle those characters such as trade mark and copyright symbols fine in nvarchar so you should look where it is getting introduced.

Comment: You should just store the data as `nvarchar` and then you won't get problems with these characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That special character is `NCHAR(65533)` but evades normal pattern matching using `LIKE`, `CHARINDEX`, `PATINDEX`, etc. I did find one way to detect it using `TRANSLATE`, by swapping the Unicode replacement character for a different Unicode character *that can't possibly be in the data already*. I picked an 8-pointed star (`✵`, `NCHAR(10037)`) but there are [so many to choose from](https://unicode-table.com/en/)...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever(things nvarchar(32));

INSERT dbo.whatever(things) VALUES
  (N'this row is just fine.'),
  (N'well, here there is a � rhombus.'),
  (N'this row is just fine too.');

SELECT things
  FROM dbo.whatever
  WHERE TRANSLATE(things, nchar(65533), N'✵') LIKE N'%✵%';
```

Output:

> well, here there is a � rhombus.

Also note the difference between `print 'hi � there';` and `print N'hi � there';` - don't be lazy, if your string is (or could contain) Unicode, *always* use the `N'prefix'`.

As Martin suggests, though, SQL Server can store whatever character is leading to the � - it is most likely because you are treating the file as ASCII, inserting them into a varchar column, or it is getting lost somewhere else along the way.